# Dynamically create table of object in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to dynamically create table of object in angular 2/typescript

Create array of objects

```
export class AppComponent {
  gameBoard= GAMEBOARD;
}

var size=10;//will be for user enter
var GAMEBOARD=[];
var x=0;
for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
for (var j=0; j < size; j++) {
  if (!GAMEBOARD[i]) {                 
      GAMEBOARD[i] = [];              
  }
  GAMEBOARD[i][j]=new GameField(x);
  x++;
}}
```

Use in template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of gameBoard">
  <game-field *ngFor="let field of gameBoard[x]" [field]="field" ></game-field>
</tr>
```

Try to input:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'game-field',
//  inputs:['field'],
template: '<td >{{field.id}}</td>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class GameFieldComponent{
@Input() field: GameField;
}
```

How to put all object from GAMEBOARD into table?

(I'm a newbie in web development and Stackoverflow so please for indulgence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you place `custom-element` inside `tr` tag, it would become invalid html and it will thrown of from table tag. You can only place `td`, `th`,etc(only table element in `tr`) all the other element/ custom element aren't allowed in `tr`

Rather you should make repeat `td` and generate content from `game-field` component. It could look something like below.

Also correct inner `ngFor` to directive loop over `x` instead of `gameBoard[x]`

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of gameBoard">
  <td *ngFor="let field of x"> 
     <game-field [field]="field"></game-field>
  </td>
</tr>
```

game-field component Template

```
template: '{{field.id}}',
```

Comment: not work - html not generated, i think this line is wrong <td *ngFor="let field of gameBoard[x]"> , but i dont know how fixed it. When i try gameBoard without [x] table shows corretly (ofcourse without field value). template: '{{field.id}}' in game-field component

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the export at the top and you redefine the GAMEBOARD after that. You should move the

```
var GAMEBOARD = [];
```

To the top.

Also, using const and let, instead of var would help you avoid these problems.